# I'm trying to use the LDAP extended operation start tls using c++. But after executing the start tls extension i'm unable to make the simple bind

Tags: c++, c, authentication, ssl, ldap

This is the part of the code i'm working with to establish the start tls extended operation. The binding is not working after the execution of start tls.

```
BerElement *ber;//extended
    struct berval *bv;
    char *retoid;
    struct berval *retdata;
    struct berval oid;

    oid.bv_val=(char*)LDAP_EXOP_START_TLS;
    oid.bv_len=strlen(oid.bv_val);

    ber=ber_alloc_t(LBER_USE_DER);
    cout<<"ber: "<<ber<<"\n";
    ber_printf(ber,"{");
    ber_printf(ber,"tO",LDAP_EXOP_START_TLS,oid);
    ber_printf(ber,"N}");
    res=ber_flatten(ber,&bv);
    ber_free(ber,1);
    cout<<"berf: "<<res<<"\n";

    res=ldap_extended_operation_s(ldap, LDAP_EXOP_START_TLS, bv, NULL, NULL, &retoid, &retdata);
    cout<<res<<"\n";
    
    
    res = ldap_simple_bind_s(ldap, user_dn,pass);//binds
cout<<"bind: "<<res<<"\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ldap_extended_operation_s() function, just use **ldap_start_tls_s()**.

ldap_start_tls_s() automatically sends request for checking StartTLS option on server before starting any communication.
See details on [man page](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=ldap_start_tls_s&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=OpenLDAP%202.6-Release&arch=default&format=html)